# How get just images IDs with Boto3 or list one by one images?

Tags: amazon-ec2, boto3

I have more than 400 images on my account and

```
client = boto3.client('ec2', region)
images = client.describe_images()
```

Work too long, more than 10 minutes.
How can I get just IDs of list Images one by one without tons of data?

Answer (score -1):

One architecture pattern is on upload of an object store the meta data of the object in a noSQL database like DynamoDB, then it would be only one query to return all the information about your S3 objects.

[Here is an AWS blog post about it](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/building-and-maintaining-an-amazon-s3-metadata-index-without-servers/)

Image describing the process.

[image]

[Here is a stackoverflow question, asking the same thing with other considerations.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40530806/is-dynamodb-suitable-as-an-s3-metadata-index)